# Undefined name 'context' in flutter navigation

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I want to navigate into one page to another an I used following code to that

Create route

```
final routes = <String,WidgetBuilder> {
   DashboardIesl.tag : (context)=>DashboardIesl()
};
```

navigation to button click

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => new DashboardIesl()
  ));
},
```

It gives the error message as follows

> Undefined name 'context'.

Comment: You would need to provide more context (pun intended). `context` is only available in stateful widgets or where you pass it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks it works!  Give it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

please show me more code,context is only available in statefull widgets,

```
onPressed: () {  Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashboardIesl()),  );}
```

I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to write onPressed() with in the class.